# play 2.5.10 application post request is hanging after some time in load test

Tags: playframework

Recently we upgraded our java based play application from play 2.4.2 to 2.5.10. After the upgrade we encountered a very strange problem where in load testing scenario our play application stops responding to POST request however application does response to GET request without any problem. POST requests do not reach to our Controller classes.

Later we revert back to play 2.4.2 and its running without any issue.

Does anybody has any clue why this can happen with play 2.5.10?

Comment: It is hard to say what could possibly be happening without more information. Did you tried with 2.5.13 (the newest version)?

Comment: It may be a problem on your filters. As you have said you have problems on POST methods, then you should have a look into your filters it may have changed from 2.4 to 2.5 [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#csrf-changes)

Comment: We were using java 1.8.0_25 which was actually causing problem with play 2.5.10. But problem got resolved when we used java 1.8.0_45.